# JavaFX java.lang.NullPointerException when TableView refresh

Tags: javafx

I try to refresh my table after adding new row but I get this error in line

```
codeCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("userId"));
```

when I call method `loadUserData()` from another controller.

First time it works ok.. only when I refresh the table.
Could you pls help ...

```
public class UserTableController implements Initializable{

    @FXML
    private TableView<UserClass> tableView;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<UserClass, String> codeCol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<UserClass, String> firstnameCol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<UserClass, String> lastnameCol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<UserClass, String> companyCol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<UserClass, String> usernameCol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<UserClass, String> emailCol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<UserClass, String> mobileCol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<UserClass, String> landlineCol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<UserClass, Boolean> adminCal;

    public ObservableList<UserClass> list;
    private  DatabaseHandler handler;
    private  Main mainApp;
    private MainController mainCont;
    private Stage stage;

    @FXML
    public  HBox bottomPane;
    @FXML
    private JFXButton addUserButton;


    @FXML
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

        loadUserData();
    }
     public void setMainApp(Main mainApp) {
         //this.mainApp = mainApp;

        // pass the main app to the drawerContentController:
        mainCont.setMainApp(mainApp);
    }

     public void loadUserData() {

        handler = DatabaseHandler.getInstance();
        list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        list.clear();

        String qu = "select * from Users";
        ResultSet rs = handler.execQuery(qu);
         int counter = 0;
        try {
            while (rs.next()) {
                String nuserId = String.valueOf(rs.getInt("userId"));
                String nfirstName = rs.getString("firstname");
                String nlastName = rs.getString("lastName");
                String ncompanyName = rs.getString("companyName");
                String nuserName = rs.getString("userName");
                String nemail = rs.getString("email");
                String nmobile = rs.getString("mobile");
                String nlandline = rs.getString("landline");
                Boolean nadmin = rs.getBoolean("isadmin");
                counter = counter + 1;
                list.add(new UserClass(nuserId, nfirstName, nlastName, ncompanyName, nuserName, nemail, nmobile, nlandline, nadmin));
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println("Error loadData : " + e);

        }
        codeCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("userId"));
        System.out.println("test loadUserData 1");
        firstnameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("FirstName"));
        lastnameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("lastName"));
        companyCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("companyName"));
        usernameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("userName"));
        emailCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("email"));
        mobileCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("mobile"));
        landlineCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("LandLine"));
      //  adminCal.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("IsAdmin"));
     // adminCal.setCellFactory(new );

     // ==== SINGLE? (CHECH BOX) ===
        adminCal.setCellValueFactory((CellDataFeatures<UserClass, Boolean> param) -> {
            UserClass userClass = param.getValue();

            SimpleBooleanProperty booleanProp = new SimpleBooleanProperty(userClass.getIsAdmin());

            // Note: singleCol.setOnEditCommit(): Not work for
            // CheckBoxTableCell.

            // When "Single?" column change.
            booleanProp.addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) -> {
                userClass.setIsAdmin(newValue);
            });
            return booleanProp;
        });

        adminCal.setCellFactory((TableColumn<UserClass, Boolean> p) -> {
            CheckBoxTableCell<UserClass, Boolean> cell = new CheckBoxTableCell<UserClass, Boolean>();
            cell.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            return cell;
        } //
        );

        tableView.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
        tableView.setItems(null);
        tableView.setItems(list);

    }
    @FXML
    private void addUserButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("/Users/UserDialog.fxml"));
        BorderPane addNewUser = loader.load();
        //mainLayout.setCenter(mainItems);

        Stage addDialogStage = new Stage();
        addDialogStage.setTitle("Add New User");
        addDialogStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);// windows model make my new stage allows on top
        addDialogStage.initOwner(stage);
        addDialogStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        Scene scene = new Scene(addNewUser);
        addDialogStage.setScene(scene);
        addDialogStage.showAndWait();

    }
}
```

and from another controller I call This `loadData` to refresh my tableview but got this error

Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException 
at Users.UserTableController.loadUserData(UserTableController.j‌​ava:128) 
at Users.UserDialogController.saveUser(UserDialogController.jav‌​a:146) 
at Users.UserDialogController.saveButtonAction(UserDialogContro‌​ller.java:85) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAcce‌​ssorImpl.java:62) 
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
```

/------------------

```
public class UserDialogController implements Initializable {

private static Main mainApp;
DatabaseHandler databaseHandler;
private MainController mainCont;
private UserTableController userTableController;


@FXML
private BorderPane borderPane;
@FXML
private Button closeButton;
@FXML
private JFXTextField txtfirstname;
@FXML
private JFXTextField txtlastname;
@FXML
private JFXTextField txtcompany;
@FXML
private JFXTextField txtusername;
@FXML
private JFXPasswordField txtpassword;
@FXML
private JFXTextField txtemail;
@FXML
private JFXTextField txtmobile;
@FXML
private JFXTextField txtlandline;
@FXML
private CheckBox cbxadmin;

 public UserDialogController() {

    databaseHandler = DatabaseHandler.getInstance();
   // mainController = new MainController();
     userTableController =  new UserTableController();
    mainApp = new Main();

}
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
}    

@FXML
private void saveButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    saveUser();
}

@FXML
private void closeImageViewAction(MouseEvent event) {
    closeAction();
}

@FXML
private void closeButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
   closeAction();
}
void closeAction() {
    Stage stage = (Stage) closeButton.getScene().getWindow();
    stage.close();
}
void saveUser(){
   //  System.out.println("USERNAME In User Dialog : " + mainApp.getUserNAME());
//    System.out.println(" My Action  :" + mainApp.getMyAction());
    String xFirstFame = txtfirstname.getText();
    String xLastName = txtlastname.getText();
    String xCompany = txtcompany.getText();
    String xUsername = txtusername.getText();
    String xPassword = txtpassword.getText();
    String xEmail = txtemail.getText();
    String xMobile = txtmobile.getText();
    String xLandLine = txtlandline.getText();
    int xAdmin = 0;
    if (cbxadmin.isSelected()) {
        xAdmin = 1;
    }

    String st = "INSERT INTO Users (FirstName,LastName,CompanyName,UserName,Password,Email,Mobile,LandLine,isAdmin ) VALUES ("
            + "'" + xFirstFame + "',"
            + "'" + xLastName + "',"
            + "'" + xCompany + "',"
            + "'" + xUsername + "',"
            + "'" + xPassword + "',"
            + "'" + xEmail + "',"
            + "'" + xMobile + "',"
            + "'" + xLandLine + "',"
            + "'" + xAdmin + "'"
            + " )";
    if (databaseHandler.execAction(st)) {
        try {

            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setHeaderText(null);
            alert.setContentText("Success ..Saved");
            alert.showAndWait();
            System.out.println("test 1");

           userTableController.loadUserData();

       //       mainController.tableView.refresh();
            closeAction();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error in add User : " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
        alert.setHeaderText(null);
        alert.setContentText("Failed ....");
        alert.showAndWait();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Add your stack errors

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Users.UserTableController.loadUserData(UserTableController.java:128)
 at Users.UserDialogController.saveUser(UserDialogController.java:146)
 at Users.UserDialogController.saveButtonAction(UserDialogController.java:85)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke

Comment: You need to show the code that leads to the exception: in particular, show how you are getting a reference to the original controller in the controller for the user dialog you show. Also, there is really no need to set the cell value factories again when you add new data to the table.

Comment: edit & delete ...